# Redeclaration error for a templated function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a setup where a templated function is inheriting another templated function.

```
template <typename DataType>
class ClassBase
{ 
  virtual void InitModel(const cv::Mat& data) {};
}

template <typename DataType>
class ClassDerived : public ClassBase<DataType>
{
  void InitModel(const cv::Mat& data) {};
}
```

Now I try to implement two specializations and one general templating for InitModel in ClassDerived in an implementation file

```
template<>
void ClassDerived<float>::InitModel(const cv::Mat& data)
{
 // initialize some things
}

template<>
void ClassDervied<cv::Vec3b>::InitModel(const cv::Mat& data)
{
  // initialize some things
}

template<typename DataType>
void ClassDerived<DataType>::InitModel(const cv::Mat& data)
{
  // initialize some things
}
```

Before I wrote this, I did not have any specializations and it was working fine. 
As soon as I added specialization, I get an error saying there was a redeclaration of the specification function. The weird part is that the redeclaration points out to the same line no. in the same file. 
Since it was working fine before specialization, I expect the file isn't being read twice.

So, why would such an error start popping up as soon as the specializations are added ?

The error is :

> /other/workspace/perception/perception_kit/object_detection/include/perception_kit/object_detection/grimson_GMM_templated_impl.tpp:129:
>   multiple definition of
>   `perception_kit::GrimsonGMMGen::InitModel(cv::Mat const&)'
>   CMakeFiles/test_obj.dir/src/object_detection_templated_test_platform.cpp.o:/other/workspace/perception/perception_kit/object_detection/include/perception_kit/object_detection/grimson_GMM_templated_impl.tpp:129:
>   first defined here

Is the problem because I am trying to derive a templated class or something else ?

Now I understand that for some, it might be a trivial problem but I have spent considerable time before I posted it here.

The base class is in BaseClass.h  (its implemented as an abstract class)
The derived class declaration is in DerivedClass.h
The derived class declaration is in DerivedClass.tpp and is included in DerivedClass.h

Comment: Is the missing angle bracket in `ClassDerived<float::InitModel` a typo? (btw, definitions of member functions of a class template should  belong to header files, unless they are explicit specializations)

Comment: Do you have template definition and implementation split into two different files?

Comment: Yeah sorry this was a lot to write. It is a typo. 
The definitions are in .h and declarations are in .tpp which has been included in .h

Comment: You have to have template definition and implementation in one file.

Comment: There is no *inheriting* in the question. Please, make sure that the code is exactly what you are testing.

Comment: @andre : I don't know about that. I had those two in different files before specializing and it worked fine. In case you're sure I'll give that a shot but I doubt it. I have read a couple of texts which says it can be in different files if included correctly.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas : Ok . I've checked everything here. I can't copy paste the exact code but now its not missing any declaration and definition components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *declare* that you have specializations for those types. Otherwise, when the compiler in a different translation unit instantiates the template it will generate code for the member functions based on the primary template. When you try to link those generated functions with your specializations the linker will see multiple definitions of the specializations.

```
// Header
template <typename T>
struct test {
   void f() {}
};
template <>
void test<int>::f();       // Declare the specialization

// Implementation (cpp, not included by client code)
template <>
void test<int>::f() { ... }
```

Note that function specializations are no longer templates, but regular functions. If different translation units include the definition of the function, then they will generate the code in multiple translation units. If you want to do that, then you can skip the declaration of the specialization and provide the definition directly, but you will need to make it `inline`:

```
// Implementation (if in header/included by user code)
template <>
inline void test<int>::f() { ... }
```

Comment: @navderm: Wait a second... the implementation file, is it a .cpp? Or are you including it from multiple translation units? A complete specialization (and for functions that is the only form of specialization) is no longer a template but a regular function. If you want that to live in a header you will need to make those specializations `inline`. Updated the answer.

Comment: For now the specializations are in .tpp file which is included in .h file.

Comment: Yep! Inline did the trick !! 
But does that not mean the code become really slow ? Because this was just an initialization function. There are other pretty extensive function that need to be template specialized . 
Or may be this is not the best place to template things ?

Comment: Did I have to add an inline function because I had the base function inlined ? Or is that always the case ?

Comment: @navderm: If you end up specializing the templates for all uses it might not make sense to use templates in the first place. As of why you need the `inline`, the keyword is only far away related to actually inlining. A specialization is just like a regular function, if you have a function in a header it will be generated in all translation units, violating the One Definition Rule. Templates are *inline* (in the ODR sense) by default, i.e. it is not a violation of the ODR if a function template is defined in multiple TUs, but specializations are no longer *templates*.

Comment: ... regarding the speed, `inline` does not force inlining, so it is still up to the compiler to decide whether the code is inlined or not, but if you want to make sure it is not inlined (barring whole program optimizations), you can move the definition of the specializations to a single translation unit (do not include the file from other TUs) and declare the specializations in the header. This will have the additional side effect of reducing compilation time.

Answer (score 2):

You already defined the base template code inline in the header (with an empty body) so you can't redefine it again later. I suspect that's the source of your problem here, NOT the specializations.

Comment: Sorry I added the virtual keyword. Is that true even with a virtual function ?

Comment: @navderm: The `virtual` keyword has no impact here, it only means that for each instantiation of the template, the member function will need to be instantiated (as virtual functions are always *odr-used*), but that does not have any effect on the issue: the compiler will generate an specialization from the definition of the template as it does not know that you will specialize it manually.